# c++ 2D vector iteration

Tags: c++, vector

i have a `std::vector< std::vector<int> > vec` Vector. I need to iterate through the outer vector and use the values in the inner vector (only 2 values stored there) like *it[0] and *it[1].

```
for (std::vector< std::vector<int> >::iterator it =  vec.begin(); it !=  vec.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it[0] << *it[1] << std::endl;
}
```

This doesn't work. I cannot find any syntax on how to get the vector elements from the vector the iterator is pointing at. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean 'it does not work'? *it gives you an instance of std::vector<int>. can this help you?

Comment: [This operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) might be a useful reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
std::cout << (*it)[0] << (*it)[1] << std::endl;
```

But really you should replace the inner vector with a `std::pair` or a `struct` of your own making, because it would be more efficient and clearer if you only ever have two elements.

Comment: I admire you could understand this!

Comment: I don't know what's so hard to understand. But thanks @JohnZwinck for understanding me ;-). now I'm using a struct for the inner values of the vector.

Comment: std::array<int,2> is also a good option if using indices is desirable